# Passing a list to Jinja2's render_template()

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list called `geolist` just below all my `import` statements followed by a series of functions, one of which appends elements to `geolist`.

***Function which is used to populate `geolist`***

```
def reverseDNS(IPlist):
    list(set(IPlist))
    print(IPlist)
    #geolist = [] --- Removed 
    for ip in IPlist:
        url = "http://ipinfo.io/" + ip + "/json"
        print(url)
        info = str(urllib.urlopen(url).read()) 
        data = json.loads(info) 
        if (("bogon" in data) == False):
            geolist.append(data['loc'])
```

This is the test method (which comes at the end) I am using to display the contents of geolist (tested to check not empty);

**Python** *(Tried this first)*

```
@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    return render_template('template.html', list=geolist)
```

*Then tried this*

```
@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    geo_list = []
    for geo in geolist:
        geo_list.append(geo)

    return render_template('template.html', list=geo_list)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Tester</h1>
      {% for n in list %}
        <p>{{ n }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass (the contents of ?) `geolist` as a parameter of `render_template()` and display it.

Thank you.

Comment: how do you execute this function which appends elements to `geolist` - Maybe you doesn't execute it. Show more code.

Comment: @furas I use a function which takes in a list as parameter. I attached the code to the post

Comment: how/where do you execute `reverseDNS` ?

Comment: `geolist` is local variable which exists only in `reverseDNS` - so you can't use it in any other function. You don't use `return` to assing to external/global variable, you don't use `global` to use external `geolist`.

Comment: @furas I have a function called main which calls `reverseDNS`. It is an implementation of traceroute. Shall I put that code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the failure? Is the page being rendered but without any list item?

Comment: do you know what means `local` and `global` variable ? Every variable created outside functions is global - you can get it value in every function and you can assign value to this variable if you use `global geolist` inside some function.

Comment: @furas I removed that and used it right under my import statements, still no luck

Comment: @qwattash The elements from the list do not render in the HTML

Comment: every variable created inside function is `local` and is destroyed when you leave function - so you have to use `return geolist` to send this list outside function or use `global geolist` to get access directly to global variable.

Comment: @furas Tried using `global geolist` both inside and outside the function. I am getting the error "global name 'geolist' is not defined"

Comment: you have to define `geolist = []` outside functions.

Comment: and check if your code in `reverseDNS` add anything to this list - maybe your `if` is incorrect and it never add `data['loc']` to list.

Comment: @furas Thank you very much for your detailed and patient answers :) I have sort of figured it out. My mistake was in my if statement for app.run which was passing an empty parameter which trickled down. Your last comment helped me find that. Thank you!